# How to update constraints animation in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview, uianimation

I want to expand view height with animation in `UITableView` cell.
It's working but animation not working as i want.
My code is something like.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         let cell = listingTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listingTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! listingTableViewCell

        //Charactristic expand
        let isExpand = isExpandViewArr[indexPath.row]

        if isExpand == true {

            cell.expandBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "down-arrow"), for: .normal)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                cell.expandViewHeight.constant = 0
                self.loadViewIfNeeded()
            }
        }else{

            cell.expandBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "up-arrow"), for: .normal)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                cell.expandViewHeight.constant = 40
                self.loadViewIfNeeded()
            }

        }

    }
```

Please check screen on link : https://ibb.co/XjjXRz5

Comment: What you mean by *It's working but animation not working as i want.* ? What was your desired behavior and what you are getting ?

Comment: It's expanding but not with animation. i want to expand height with animation.

Comment: @nico beat me to it. Check out his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to set the `cell.expandViewHeight.constant = 40` outside of the animation call and simply call `self.layoutIfNeeded()` inside. Like so:

```
cell.expandViewHeight.constant = 40
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {            
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = listingTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listingTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! listingTableViewCell

    //Charactristic expand
    let isExpand = isExpandViewArr[indexPath.row]

    if isExpand == true {

        cell.expandBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "down-arrow"), for: .normal)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tblView.beginUpdates()
            cell.expandViewHeight.constant = 0
            self.tblView.endUpdates()
        }
    }else{

        cell.expandBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "down-arrow"), for: .normal)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tblView.beginUpdates()
            cell.expandViewHeight.constant = 40
            self.tblView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```